# Import dataset into MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

I am trying to insert this database into MongoDB using Studio 3T. I can import the bson without any issues (the countries and timezones) by selecting the parent folder and using `BSON - mongodump folder` option. However I cannot figure out how to import the split cities dataset.

I have tried all the options available on Studio3T and attempted to change the filename to gz however it always fails to import. I don't know what file format the cities are in.

Normally I do not have any issue importing but I cannot figure out how to do this. How would I achieve this?

The source DB is here https://github.com/VinceG/world-geo-data

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data is nothing but a big .bson file that has been gzipped up and split into various parts. I was not able to import the .bson file successfully. However, I could unzip the file at least without an error using the following commands and [GZip for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gzip.htm)

```
copy /b city_split_aa+city_split_ab+city_split_ac+city_split_ad+city_split_ae cities.bson.gz
gzip -d cities.bson
```

Comment: Hmm, been playing with this for ~ hour and I get a failed decompression issue but are still given a 900mb file. It wont let me import it though

Comment: Yeah, I reckon, I should have tried that myself properly before answering... ;( It's not as trivial as I thought... 7zip can normally handly literally anything but this one it doesn't seem to deal gracefully with. Let's see if the update here gets you a little further.

Comment: I'm on a mac and struggling to join the file. I understand cp is used instead of copy on a mac but what does /b do?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. That command basically copies files in a binary fashion. All it does is read all bytes sequentially from the files and append them into one big file.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for the help. You were really helpful

Comment: So how did you eventually import that data? I didn't see a metadata file and I seem to remember that my Studio3T didn't like that.

Comment: The joined file I renamed to .bson and the metadata file allowed me to import it